# Automatically build and deploy a gem when committing to GitHub

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems

There are a ton of APIs which watch and respond to GitHub activity. For instance, you can set CodeClimate to automatically review your code every time you commit. Similarly, you can use Travis CI to ensure that your tests are passing. Is there also a service that will automatically build your code into a Ruby Gem and then deploy it to [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/)?

Comment: You could to it as part of your Travis CI build. See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/rubygems/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis CI allows to deploy Gems to rubygems.org after a successful build. The configuration is documented at http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/rubygems.

For your case, it seems you want to update your gem whenever you push to Github (and have a successful build). You could achieve this by adding the following configuration to your `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  provider: rubygems
  api_key: "YOUR API KEY"
```

The API key can be encrypted (which is recommended) by locally running (after having installed the `travis` gem)

```
travis encrypt --add deploy.api_key
```

Comment: Also you can simply run `travis setup rubygems`--assuming you have the `travis` gem installed. Thanks again for the prompt reply!